# Склоняется ли слово "макадамия" в этом случае?

Tags: склонение

**Ядра ореха макадамия (макадамии)?**

Ответ Грамоты на похожий вопрос:

> Скажите, пожалуйста, как правильно: "С маслом ореха макадамиЯ" или "С
> маслом ореха макадамиИ"? Спасибо!
>
> Лучше не склонять.

Но также есть и другой ответ:

> Добрый день, уважаемая справка. Задаю свой вопрос еще раз, может быть
> он затерялся. Как правильно сказать - ядро ореха фундука (миндаля),
> или ядро ореха фундук (миндаль). Большое спасибо...
>
> Правильно: *ядро ореха фундука (миндаля)*.

Есть ли правило?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Правильно: **ядра ореха макадамии.**

1. Макада́мия — род древесных растений. Торговое наименование плодов этих растений — «орех макадамия».
2. Итак,  есть дерево макадамия и орех макадамия. Это словосочетания  родового и видового названий, оформленные  **по принципу приложений (согласование в падеже)**: дерево, орех – это определяемые существительные, а макадамия – видовое название в роли приложения.
   Примечание. Возможно сочетания и по принципу  управления: орех макадамии (то есть орех дерева макадамии). Род у видового и родового названия разный.
3. **Реально** сочетание «орех макадамия» используется в большинстве описательных текстов  именно по  принципу приложения**, то есть согласуется в падеже: ядра (чего?)  ореха макадамии, масло ореха макадамии.

Например: Масло растительное Great Hearts of Africa **ореха макадамии**, 250 мл.

Хотя отклонения встречаются, но **вряд ли их можно считать обоснованными**.  Кстати, интересно было бы ознакомиться с таким **обоснованием.**

Также: орех макадамии сладкий, макадамия  сладкая на вкус – это варианты сочетания по роду.

4. Соответственно, **рекомендации  Грамоты.ру,** да еще в такой форме ("лучше"), представляются некорректными. Чем всё-таки лучше? Это желательно указать.  Как вариант, **опрощение** связи согласования, переход к примыканию, но  тогда надо указывать причину и область применения.
5. Какое есть правило?  Это общее правило, с которым можно ознакомиться, к примеру,  в книге "Краткая русская грамматика"
   http://slovari.ru/default.aspx?s=0&p=5312&0a0=1718#354

§ 354. **Приложение** – это согласование, при котором в отношения определяемого и определяющего вступают существительные. Согласуемой формой при приложении является **падеж;** формы рода и числа в согласовании не участвуют: они могут совпадать (гриб боровик) или не совпадать (гриб сыроежка).

Существительные, выступающие в роли приложения, обозначают качества и свойства: старик-отец, поэт-новатор,  **видовые признаки:** месяц май, дерево сосна, ягода черника,; имена, фамилии, прозвища, клички: гражданин Петров, девочка Оля, собака Шарик; географические названия: город Москва; собственные имена предметов: газета "Труд".

§ 355. Смысловые отношения при приложении могут быть более или менее **слитными**. При наибольшей слитности признака с предметом приложение (обычно **препозитивное**) **теряет способность к словоизменению** и ведет себя как часть сложного слова: бой-баба, козырь-девка, горе-охотник, чудо-дерево, **жар-птица**, царь-колокол, царь-пушка, царь-девица.
Примечание. Сюда же относятся .. названия трав: **ковыль-трава**, плакун-трава, Иван-чай.

§ 356. Несклоняемость приложения может сопровождаться не только **опрощением согласовательной связи, но и сближением ее со связью примыкания.** Так, в современной обиходно-бытовой речи тенденцию к неизменяемости все больше проявляют постпозитивные приложения-топонимы: озеро Байкал, на озере Байкал.

Все эти случаи по существу **выходят за рамки приложения,** поскольку о приложении как разновидности согласования можно говорить только там, где налицо **словоизменение обоих членов словосочетания.**

Answer (score 1):

**А в рекламе всё возможно**, например: Цены, характеристики, отзывы **на ядра ореха макадамия.** Выбор по параметрам. 116 магазинов. Доставка из  Москвы и других регионов.

А так выглядит товарное название  в тех же магазинах, товар которых рекламируется: ***Орех макадамия очищенный***.

Значит, в рекламе так лучше, а почему? Причина, наверное, есть. **Макадамия** – это не очень известный продукт, многие к нему относятся настороженно. Да и название не самое простое, к тому же   женского рода.  А здесь нужно точное воспроизведение, поэтому  склонение и нежелательно. Вот и пишут: «Купите орешки макадамия».

Похожее правило действует **для географических названий в специальной литературе**, где точность необходима. Не рекомендуют склонять  малоизвестные названия в обычных текстах. Также топонимы на  ово/ево и ыно/ино не очень любят изменять по падежам, хотя правила рекомендуют.

Вероятно, ***ядра ореха макадамия*** – это **рекламный вариант**. Надо бы  еще **кавычки** добавить, но для простоты их опускают.