# Неизменяемые прилагательные и существительные

Tags: неизменяемые

Как отличить неизменяемое **прилагательное** от неизменяемого **существительного**?

Например:

> Я стою в плаще хаки.

Я стою в плаще (каком) хаки? По идее, должно быть прилагательным, но смущает тот факт, что этот вопрос может характеризовать роль в предложении, а не части речи.

Как здесь, например:

> Я ем орехи макадамия.

Орехи (какие) макадамия, хотя слова "макадамия" является по словарю только существительным.

*Как это разграничивать?*

Comment: Сущ. макадамия склоняется, то есть изменяется по числам и падежам.  https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Макадамия

Comment: Скажите, пожалуйста, как правильно: "С маслом ореха макадамиЯ" или "С маслом ореха макадамиИ"? Спасибо!
Лучше не склонять.

Comment: http://gimnazia9-gro.blogspot.com/   http://urokirusskogo.ru/videouroki/6-klass/neizmenjaemye-sushhestvitelnye/   https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/461861/%d0%a1%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%8f%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b2-%d1%8d%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bc-%d1%81%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%b5